# Upgrading Intel DC S3500 HP OEM firmware without Windows Server?

Tags: ssd, hpe, firmware-update

I have a second hand 800GB SSD Intel DC S3500 series (Model VK0800GDJYA).

The Intel DC S3500 series suffers from the 8MB bug if the firmware is not updated: the capacity of the SSD suddenly fells to 8MB, for instance after a power outage.

Some of these SSD are OEM branded and run OEM firmware. Mine is an HP one, with firmware HPG1.
Unfortunately, **the firmware of OEM SSDs from Intel cannot be updated with Intel's Firmware upgrade tool** and one must use the updates provided by the OEM.

I could find this firmware upgrader on HP's website, but it requires Windows Server 2008 or 2012:
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX-54629fea2b664c73bb4698d1fb#tab2

I don't have Windows Server software (nor any HP Proliant server) but some HP desktops/notebooks if necessary.

Is there still some way to upgrade the firmware of such SSD without Windows Server?

Comment: Ancillary question: If the SSD with HP firmware is already bricked with the 8MB bug. Is there also a way to unbrick it?

Comment: What specifically do you want? There are the Linux and ESXi updaters https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_8e5b2fcdde9045389fe6b61855 https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_54d606695ae94263a4e926dbe4  but you don't mention what you want, only "not Windows". It's probably also included on some recent bootable SPP DVD.  I suppose the overall issue might be whether any of the HPE updaters run properly in a non-Proliant environment, but these are at least non-Windows options.